# how to populate list <>in foreach request.files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, dropzone.js

I use **dropzone js** to upload multiple images to server and save each image path in database using linq so I tried to populate list with the paths of images and then get access to the list to save the paths in the list in linq but the list wont populate

Anybody know what's the problem ?

```
  public partial class additemdetails : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
   DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
    List<string> img = new List<string>();


item itm = new item();

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        List<string> img = new List<string>();

        foreach (string s in Request.Files)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[s];
            int fileSizeInBytes = file.ContentLength;
            string fileName = file.FileName;// Request.Headers["X-File-Name"];
            string fileExtension = "";
            fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            string savedFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + fileExtension;
            string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/img/items/");
            string filename = path + savedFileName;

            img.Add(filename);
            itm.img1 = img[0];
            file.SaveAs(filename);

        }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure this is compiling correctly? I thought [`Request.Files`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files(v=vs.110).aspx) is a collection of `HttpPostedFile`, not strings

Comment: The given code in c# should not compile. The declaration for 'fileName' varibale is appearing twice as -- string fileName

Comment: @Rhumborl yes it's compiling correctly and the images uploading work fine but the list<> not!

Comment: @VivekN there are fileName and filename

Comment: Where is `itm` defined?

Comment: @LoganB.Lehman before protected void Page_Load

Comment: Where are you trying to access `img`? `img` only exists within the scope of your `Page_Load` function.

Comment: @ajjawi - Could you please append your code to show this?

Comment: @MattBurland yes it's only exist within scope of Page_Load

Comment: @LoganB.Lehman appended !

Comment: So what makes you think it's not populated? Did you step through the code? Is `Request.Files` even populated?

Comment: @LoganB.Lehman request.file for sure is populated because there's file image uploaded to the server and the field in database that assigned with the list[] is NULL that's why i think it's not populated

Comment: Or is it because you are creating a _new_ `List<string> img = new List<string>();` inside `Page_Load` so the class-level one is always empty?